# How to know if two strings are on the same line?

Tags: perl

I have a file that gets lines added to it each day, which contains each new day's date, and a text saying that an action has been done successfully.

What I'm trying to do is to read each line and get the one with the date of today and the word 'successfully' in it. If it does, then I'll create a file in which I put the line inside so that I can access it.

Here is what the code currently is:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
 open(FILE,"verif_succes.txt");
    if (grep{localtime()} <FILE> && grep{/successfully/} <FILE>){
       print "found\n";
    }else{
       print "word not found\n";
    }
    close FILE;
```

`verif_succes.txt` contains lines like this:

```
info    2023/10/13 08:58:42     SYSTEM: task finished successfully.
```

Now I want to know how can I verify if today's date and the word 'successfully' are in the same line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet:

Try this out -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $file = "verif_succes.txt";
my $today = strftime("%Y/%m/%d", localtime);

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;

while(my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp $line;
    if(($line =~ /$today/) && ($line =~ /successfully/)){
        print "FOUND: $line\n";
    } else {
        print "NOT FOUND\n";
    }
}

close($fh);
```

verif_succes.txt:

```
info    2023/10/13 08:58:42     SYSTEM: task finished successfully.
info    2023/10/14 08:58:42     SYSTEM: task finished successfully.
info    2023/10/18 08:58:42     SYSTEM: task finished successfully.
```

Result:

```
$perl read_file_verify.pl
NOT FOUND
NOT FOUND
FOUND: info    2023/10/18 08:58:42     SYSTEM: task finished successfully.
```

Comment: Note that you are printing NOT FOUND multiple times, but the OP only printed it once.

Comment: Why do you do that in a while loop? It should be enough to just look at the last line of the file. And you can shorten the program by skipping the `chomp()` and just printing out the result without the trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

While there are now answers I'd like to point out a common error of the uninitiated, which has not been commented on at all.  Once we are at it, I'd also like to show some alternatives.

The program shown in the question makes it certain that the two matched fragments are NOT on the same line!  This is because each `<FILE>` in that `if` condition reads a line from the file to which `FILE` filehandle is attached.

So in

```
grep{localtime()} <FILE>     # reads a line
```

that `<FILE>` reads a line and returns a string with it, on which `grep` then runs, and then in

```
grep{/successfully/} <FILE>  # reads another line
```

this `<FILE>` reads the next line (and runs `grep` on it).  So by construction this matches things on separate lines. It could happen, by accident, that one of these lines *also* has the other word so that the output is correct, but that would be a matter of "luck" <sup>†</sup> and the code is clearly broken.

Those `<>` are an [I/O operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators), which reads a line from a file via a "filehandle" inside.  It reads a line from a file every time it is invoked.

So what you want is to read with it once, what returns a line which gets stored in a string.  Then parse that string to find what you need in it.  As shown in other answers.

---

Let me imagine that we have a huge log file (`~1Gb`) and hate taking many seconds to process it when the strings of interest are at the very end and the whole program would otherwise run in a few 100ms or so.  (Or, perhaps, we need *the last* occurrence in the file.)

Then read the file from the back, using [File::ReadBackwards](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards)  Also, once we talk alternatives, I'd like to introduce a library for date-time processing, [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).  (While in this case `localtime` + `strftime` may well be perfect for the job.<sup>‡</sup>)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime;
use File::ReadBackwards;

my $file = shift // 'verif_succes.txt';
# Or, to enforce input:
# my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

my $bw = File::ReadBackwards->new($file) or die $!; 

my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
my $today = $now->ymd('/');
    
while ( my $line = $bw->readline ) { 
    chomp $line;

    if ( $line =~ /$today.*successfully/ ) { 
        say "Found line: |$line|";
        last;                       # find just last such line
    }   
}
```

A line can be processed in a more sophisticated (better) manner, see for example ikegami's answer.  As for `DateTime` use, one can also construct the date *string* directly, if there is no reason to have a date-time object around (`$now` above)

```
my $today = DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local')->ymd('/');
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  *Bad* luck really, as it would make the bug harder to notice.  It is best if errors show clearly and dramatically in development, ideally every time and on every input.

<sup>‡</sup> If dates or timestamps need be sensibly manipulated as date-times then one needs a library. An example: read from the back and save lines until we get to *yesterday*'s date (so to assemble all today's text, to be processed later).

With `localtime` we get a *string* which would be very hard to manipulate as a date-time, for example to find yesterday's date.
In such a situation we normally use that string to construct a date-time object with some library, which then easily gives us a day before.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
my $found = grep { localtime() && /successfully/ } <FILE>;
```

---

BUT!

`localtime()` is not what you want there.

```perl
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $today = strftime( "%Y/%m/%d", localtime );

my $found = grep { /$today/ && /successfully/ } <FILE>;
```

Give that the order is known, we can merge that into one regex

```perl
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $today = strftime( "%Y/%m/%d", localtime );

my $found = grep { /$today.*successfully/ } <FILE>;
```

And we can make it more reliable.

```perl
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $today = strftime( "%Y/%m/%d", localtime );

my $found = grep { /^ \S++ \s++ $today \s \S++ \s++ .*successfully /x } <FILE>;
```

But that requires reading the entire file. We could stop as soon as a match is found.

```perl
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $today = strftime( "%Y/%m/%d", localtime );

my $found = 0;
while ( <FILE> ) {
   if ( / ^\S++ \s++ $today \s \S++ \s++ .*successfully /x ) {
      $found = 1;
      last;
   }
}
```

Finally, let's address that `open`. You're using global variable (bad!), you're using 2-arg `open` (bad!), and you're not checking for errors (bad!). Fixed:

```perl
my $qfn = "verif_succes.txt";
open( my $FILE, "<", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open `$qfn`: $!\n" );
```

---

So the whole program is

```perl
use v5.14;        # Enables strict and say
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $today = strftime( "%Y/%m/%d", localtime );

my $qfn = "verif_succes.txt";
open( my $FILE, "<", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open `$qfn`: $!\n" );

my $found = 0;
while ( <$FILE> ) {
   if ( / ^\S++ \s++ $today\s\S++ \s++ .*successfully /x ) {
      $found = 1;
      last;
   }
}

say $found ? "found" : "not found";
```